# Dolphin/Nautilus Both Cause System Wide Freeze On Access NTFS Partition

Tags: nautilus, freeze, ntfs, dolphin

Ubuntu 12.04.1, using either file manager to mount my Windows 7 NTFS partition causes a system wide lock up.  Only solution is Alt + SysRq + REISUB.  I've run CHKDSK /R on volume to no avail.  Anyone?

Comment: Could you run Nautilus with terminal and try to mount your ntfs partition?What is the error's output?

Comment: Ah missed this, do you know the specific commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the contents of C's .Trash directory from within Windows solved this issue.  I guess it became corrupt, maybe from changes made within Windows itself?

Answer (score 0):

Type `nano /etc/fstab` at a terminal. One of the lines should look similar to this:

`/dev/sda1       "/media/Windows XP Professional"        ntfs-3g ro,defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0 0`

Only, obviously, it will have Windows 7 instead.
Please show us that line. We can't help you without it. (After you've read it, press CTRL-X to exit Nano.)

If you want to give a shot at fixing it yourself, then type `sudo fdisk -l`. You should get something similar to this:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63   196527491    98263714+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       196528126   312498175    57985025    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       308310016   312498175     2094080   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       196528128   308310015    55890944   83  Linux
```

See how one of them has an ID of 7? That's the Windows partition. Note which device it's on (in this case, `/dev/sda1`.)
Now type `ls /media` and note the exact spelling of the Windows folder. (In my case, "Windows XP Professional")

Go to your Terminal and type
`sudo mount -t ntfs -r nls=utf8,umask=0222 /dev/sda1 "/media/Windows XP Professional"`
**EXCEPT** replace `/dev/sda1` with the device you noted earlier, and `"/media/Windows XP Professional"` with `/media` + the folder name you noted earlier. (Be sure to include the quotation marks, *especially* if the name has spaces in it.)

If you get any errors, type `sudo umount /dev/sda1` (or whatever location you found eralier,) and then try again.
If you decide to try it yourself, and can't fix an error, please tell me, and include the error that the Terminal gives you. (To define code in a comment, surround it with these: `` ` ``)

Comment: I should add Windows & linux are hard partitioned, each on their own HDD, `nano /etc/fstab` shows sdb only.

Comment: `sudo fdisk -l`: `Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63      610469      305203+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          610470   357165760   178277645+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       357167104   976769023   309800960    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT`

Comment: Try adding this to your `/etc/fstab` file anyway: `/dev/sda1       /C        ntfs-3g ro,defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0 0` Then reboot and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

on wubi install 11.10 am don't have this problem.
on host folder acess (ntfs, windows patricion),nautilus is work perfect
on 12.04 if mount usb stick (ntfs system on it) no problem